# How can I clear previous output in Terminal in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, buffer

I know the `clear` command that 'clears' the current screen, but it does this just by printing lots of newlines - the cleared contents just get scrolled up.

Is there a way to completely wipe all previous output from the terminal so that I can't reach it even by scrolling up?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this that works in a shell script?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I don't think so. Anyway, now I think I don't need this at all. I am satisfied with `Command+K`.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg my updated answer (and one other answer) shows you how to do it from a script.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command

Answer (score 1352, accepted):

#### To clear the terminal manually:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for newer keyboards

#### To clear the terminal from within a shell script;

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "k" using command down'
```

Comment: @fearless_fool http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/31887 might do it?  If it does, please let me know!

Comment: Well, yes, but see below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26615036/558639) for a better way altogether.

Comment: If you accidentally pressed this, how would one go about viewing the cleared buffer?

Comment: @JoshPinter, just don't press it by accident.  :)  (Consider using `clear` for all cases *except* where you need the scrollback history to actually disappear, e.g. when you are going to print.)

Comment: @Wildcard Fair enough. :) Good advice on using `clear`. I feel like they should be reversed, though. Typing `clear` seems more intentional than hitting `Command + K`.

Comment: @JoshPinter `clear` is a command that works in all the terminals (OS X's native "Terminal", X11's xterm, iTerm etc.).  So it looks the environment variable `TERM` and outputs an appropriate set of characters which clear the terminal.  `Command + K` only works in "Terminal".  Terminal also provides a lot of commands to clear parts of the terminal (`Command + L` etc.).

Comment: @JoshPinter you can see that `clear` is doing things based on `TERM` by doing stuff like: `TERM=xterm clear | hexdump` and `TERM=tek clear | hexdump`.  The output is different, so the character `clear` outputs are clearly (!) dependent on `TERM` variable.

Comment: problem is, mac OS doesn't discriminate which terminal window to clear. if the script is running in one, but your focus is in another, it'll clear the one with the focus, not the one with the script

Comment: This doesn't play nice with tmux for some reason. It's visually clearing the tmux bar

Answer (score 133):

#### A better way to clear the screen from within a script...

If you're using the OS X Terminal app (as stated by the OP), a better approach (thanks to [Chris Page's answer to *How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command/113168#113168)) is just this:

```
clear && printf '\e[3J'
```

or more concisely ([hat tip to user *qiuyi*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-can-i-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x/29876027#29876027)):

```
printf '\33c\e[3J'
```

which clears the scrollback buffer as well as the screen. There are other options as well. See [Chris Page's answer to *How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command/113168#113168) for more information.

#### Original answer

The AppleScript answer given in this thread works, *but* it has the nasty side effect of clearing *any* terminal window that happens to be active.  This is surprising if you're running the script in one window and trying to get work done in another!

You avoid this by refining the AppleScript to only clear the screen if it is frontmost by doing this (taken from [MattiSG's answer to *How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command/31887#31887)):

```
osascript -e 'if application "Terminal" is frontmost then tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'
```

... but as when it's not the current window, the output will stack up until it becomes current again, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: I used the "better way" in ``.bash_profile`` and it's awesome because I no longer get the glitched buffer sometimes when opening a new terminal window.

Comment: This is the most conceptually correct answer.  qiuyi's answer avoids the && at the sacrifice of a little readability.  If Alok's answer could be extended to clear the terminal that is running the current script, it would be an improvement, but this simpler.

Comment: Is there a way to bind a command, eg, `ctrl+l`, to do the same thing as `printf '\33c\e[3J'` using `.inputrc` ?

Comment: I could not figure out with `.inputrc` but this worked in my `.bash_profile`: `bind '"\C-k": "printf \\\\33c\\\\e[3;\n"'`

Comment: The `printf` code works in the normal terminal app, but not in the built-in terminal of PHPStorm. Anyone knows why?

Comment: This & another answer have some overlap, and I always waste time figuring out who the original is so I'm not awarding point miners for duped work. Here, fearless has [`clear && printf '\e[3J'` from the start in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26615036/1). And as (maybe a little obliquely) noted, the `printf '\33c\e[3J'` improvement [is lifted from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876027/1028230) and [repeated here in a  edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26615036/5). So we've got an answer & an improvement that's duped back into the original; upvotes for everyone!

Comment: @kortina thanks! Nice trick! Didn't know about bind with bash.

Answer (score 87):

#### To delete the last output only:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

#### To clear the terminal completely:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to _clear_ the screen but still have the input be there if I scroll up above the fold?

Comment: @Qasim Under Linux `clear -x` keeps scrollback intact, don't have a mac at hand to test there

Comment: @Andreas I just tested it out in Zsh on macOS Catalina, and it does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: For iTerm2 users, Cmd + Alt + L can delete the last line.

Comment: For iTerm2 users, Cmd + Alt + L can delete the last line: https://superuser.com/a/1767681/114723 (called `Clear to Previous Mark`)

Answer (score 67):

The pretty way is `printf '\33c\e[3J'`

Comment: This is the best way. We should define alias like `alias cls='printf "\33c\e[3J"'`

Comment: Works in iTerm2 as well

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, `\33c` performs the equivalent of the `clear` command, which basically just scrolls the screen until you can't see it's previous contents. It clears the screen, but not the scroll back buffer (i.e. you can still use the scroll bars to see the old output). Add the `\e[3J` to actually clear the scroll back buffer.

Comment: @EirNym, add `function cls { printf '\33c\e[3J\33c' }` line in `~/.profile` (or system-wide `/etc/profile`). This should work for desktop environments in macOS, FreeBSD, Linux etc. Note the extra `\33c` is for clearing the extra `\e[3J` literal in non-macOS (basically for Linux/FreeBSD, we only need `printf '\33c'`).

Comment: @luiss What is the code `\33c`? Is there an official document for the full list of similar code's meaning in MacOS?

Comment: Can you do a similar magic trick just to clear just the last command and its output? (equivalent of ⌘L on Mac)

Answer (score 37):

Put this in your *.bash_profile* or *.bashrc* file:

```
function cls {
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'
}
```

Comment: This answer still works great in Big Sur! It clears the output of the current terminal tab (other windows/tabs are not cleared)

Answer (score 22):

On Mac OS X Terminal, this functionality is already built in to the Terminal Application as menu *View* → *Clear Scrollback* (the default is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>).

So you can re-assign this as you like with Apple's Keyboard shortcuts. Just add a new shortcut for Terminal with the command "Clear Scrollback". (I use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, because it's similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the current screen contents, without clearing the buffer.)

I am not sure how you would use this in a script (maybe AppleScript as others have pointed out).

Comment: As of Yosemite (10.10), `View->Clear Scrollback` is no longer present in Terminal's menu.  The keyboard shortcut `CMD` + `K` still works, though.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Looks like `Clear Scrollback` has just moved from `View` to `Edit` in Yosemite.

Answer (score 11):

With [Mac OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite), use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to clear the scrollback in Terminal.app.

Answer (score 9):

Or you can send a [page break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) (ASCII form feed) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

While this technically just starts a new page, this has the same net effect as all the other methods, while being a lot faster (except for the <kbd>Apple</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> solution, of course).

And because this is an ASCII control command, and it works in all shells.

Comment: That clears the screen but leaves the scrollback buffer intact.

Comment: it is not the same if you want to use cmd + f for exemple

Comment: That's not how Control-L works in a shell. Shells bind the Control-L (Form Feed) input to a command that clears the screen in some appropriate way, which is not by sending a Form Feed to the terminal. Terminals treat FF just like New Line and advance the cursor one row. Shells usually use terminfo to look up the bytes to send to the terminal. That is usually `clear=\E[H\E[2J`, which moves the cursor to the home position (ESC [ H) and erases the display (ESC [ 2 J). This is why it's important to use the `clear` command instead of hard-coding the entire sequence when doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> will clear previous output.

To clear entered text, first jump left with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then clear the text to the right of the pointer with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Visual examples:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
clear && printf '\e[3J'
```

clears out everything, and it works well on OS X as well. Very neat.

Comment: beautiful, I was just using `clear` which leaves some stuff when you scroll back up.  no more!

Answer (score 6):

Do the right thing; do the thing right!

Clear to previous mark: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Clear to previous bookmark: Option + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Clear to start: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to your configuration file would get you a new command to do it.

```
alias clearwipe='printf "\33c\e[3J"'
```

After reload `clearwipe` would be the new command to completely wipe all previous output from the terminal so that you can't reach it even by scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the previous answers to work (on macOS).

A combination worked for me -

```
IO.write "\e[H\e[2J\e[3J"
```

This clears the buffer and the screen.

Comment: What is IO.write? I had to replace it with printf to get it working.
Thanks anyway. This one works best for me

Comment: I'm not sure why I chose `IO.write`. It should work the same however you decide to print those characters to the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

This works on MacOS v13

```bash
tput reset
```

Comment: `reset` doesn't normally clear the scrollback, which is what this Q&A is about. It resets the terminal, which clears the screen. Resetting the terminal is usually undesirable.

Comment: mentioned command does clear all previous output as well as scrollback, that's what OP asked for. It's a different way to achieve the same.

Answer (score -3):

Typing the following in the terminal will *erase* your history (meaning using up arrow will get you nothing), but it will not clear the screen:

```
history -c
```

Comment: It does.
@phil does it deletes them permanently from the disk, or are they still retrievable some way?

Comment: Basically it deletes the file ~/.bash_history, so if you can recover that, you can recover the commands that have been cleared

Comment: No it doesn't work. Scrolled up history still exist, and I can scroll up to see them again.

Comment: Not what was asked. This clears the history, not the current buffer, which are two very different things.

Comment: Not what was asked, _and harmful_; I was just bitten by this, and my history contained important stuff.

Comment: This command actually clears the `scrolled up history` for the ACTIVE TERMINAL ONLY. Once closed, re-opening the terminal has the history restored.

Answer (score -3):

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> works for macOS. It clears the entire terminal output, but the environment remains.

Comment: This is the same answer as the accepted one written 8 years ago.