# Tmux clear history in bash vi mode

Tags: bash, vim, command-line, terminal, tmux

I just recently switched to using bash vi mode with `set -o vi` setting in my `.bash_profile`.  But this leads a problem

I had a tmux mapping that would run the `clear-history` command when I pressed `<ctrl>+k`.  This was the relevant mapping

```
bind -n C-k clear-history
```

This does not work in bash vi mode, probably because vi mode takes precedence.  How do I resolve or work around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could change the key, this is what I use:

```
# reset & clear history
bind r send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history
```

You have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

`k` can indeed be used but if you also move across panels (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>hkjl</kbd>), it may become confusing.

In any case this work by just using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

```
bind -n C-k send-keys C-l \; run-shell "sleep .3s; tmux clear-history"
```

Without using the sleep:

```
bind -n C-k send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me , it doesn't clear history.  I can scroll through history still with `<ctrl>+b [`

Comment: the mappings of to use `r` instead of `k` ?

Comment: Didn't quite get that, what do you mean?  I copied what you had in your answer and pasted it in my `.tmux.conf` and its clearing screen but not history, since I can scroll back through it even after pressing it

Comment: I think it's just executing `C-l` and not the `clear-history` after that

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I sort of don't want to use a solution that uses sleep.. Any other option?

Comment: I updated the answer, give a try ( interesting issue by the way)

Comment: Hmmm any way I can enter a configuration in the `inputrc` that sends a command to the attached tmux shell pane?

Comment: Hope this could help: http://minimul.com/increased-developer-productivity-with-tmux-part-5.html

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543684/how-can-i-clear-scrollback-buffer-in-tmux), I have the following tmux mapping:

```
bind-key -n C-k send-keys -R \; send-keys Escape C-l a \; clear-history
```

There are many variants of this (each with pros and cons, and for different use cases); see the linked question.