# How to clear-history in all panes in tmux?

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, tmux

Is there a way to do `clear-history` in all panes of all tmux sessions?

Tmux gets super slow after a couple days and I figure it might be because of the long scrollback buffers in a bunch of sessions.

Using Tmux 2.5 on macOS with iTerm2.

Related:
[How can I clear scrollback buffer in Tmux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543684/how-can-i-clear-scrollback-buffer-in-tmux)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set the window history limit to some small number, so every new pane will have a maximum history. In your `.tmux.conf` file you can set the window history limit with:

```
set -g history-limit 1024
```