# Console Clear - Symfony Console Component

Tags: symfony, console

I'm writing a console app using Symfony 2 Console Component, and I want to run a console clear command before (or as) the first line of my app.

I have done some research and am struggling to find if this is possible.

Answer (score 25):

I have been looking for similar functionality. There is nothing built-in to the symfony console that can clear the screen as far as I can tell, but you can still achieve the `clear` behavior by using the escape code for resetting the terminal like so:

```
$output->write(sprintf("\033\143"));
```

See the post "[Clear the Ubuntu bash screen for real](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367075/155248)" and "[What commands can I use to reset and clear my terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/123007)" for a more extensive explanation of the codes, and this symfony console [pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11589/files#diff-44bdc59351edcf8132a06cb61c9088ccR46), where I got the code from, that attempted to emulate the `clear` functionality.

Comment: Even though PHP has a `shell_exec('<any terminal command>')` it did not work for me for clearing the terminal with a `clear`. But sending `\033\143` to the output worked, which I think is the escape code for CTRL + C on a mac.