# How to clear the entire terminal (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I had an issue. Using the clear or cls command in powershell clears only the visible portion of the terminal,I would like to know how to clear the entire terminal?

I use VSCode by the way.

Comment: Please specify your question. What is the invisible portion that is not cleared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear a terminal screen for real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-a-terminal-screen-for-real)

Comment: It depends upon the terminal.

Comment: Both `clear` and `cls` are aliases for the PowerShell cmdlet `Clear-Host`. I do not have the problem you seem to have in a PowerShell console.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The question is about **clearing *both* the screen *and the scrollback buffer* in the *integrated terminal* of *Visual Studio Code***, and the ***next* section** addresses that.

  - *Update*: **While the commands built into the shells used to *not* clear the scrollback buffer too, as of Visual Studio Code v1.86 they *do*** - see the last section for details.
- To clear both the screen and the scrollback buffer **in a *regular* console / terminal / in Windows Terminal**:

  - On *Windows* and *Linux*: Use `Clear-Host` (whose aliases are `cls` and on Windows only, also `clear`; on Linux and macOS, `clear` refers to the external `/usr/bin/clear` utility, which has the same effect on Linux only).
  - On *macOS*: Execute `` Write-Host -NoNewLine "`e[2J`e[3J`e[H" `` from PowerShell, or `printf '\033[2J\033[3J\033[H'` from POSIX-compatible shells; in PowerShell 7.4+ on macOS 14+ (Sonoma or higher), `[Console]::Clear()` works now too.

---

**To also clear the *scrollback buffer*, not just the *visible portion* of the terminal** in **Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal**, use one of the following methods:

- **Caveat**: The following methods do not play nicely with *PowerShell* (both editions, up to at least v7.4.1; other shells seem to be fine): Even though clearing works fine, PowerShell is then confused about the cursor position when the next command is typed - this problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #19479](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19479).
- Use the ***command palette***:

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> and type `tclear` to match the `Terminal: Clear` command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Use the **integrated terminal's *context menu***:

  - Right-click in the terminal and select `Clear` from the context menu.
  - On **Windows**, you may have to **enable the integrated terminal's context menu first**, given that by default right-clicking *pastes* text from the clipboard:
    Open the settings (<kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>) and change setting `terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior` to either `default` or `selectWord` (the latter selects the word under the cursor before showing the context menu).
- Use a ***keyboard shortcut*** from inside the integrated terminal (current as of v1.71 of VSCode):

  - On *macOS*, a shortcut exists *by default*: <kbd>Cmd+K</kbd>
  - On *Linux* and *Windows*, you can define an analogous **custom key binding**, <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, as follows, by directly editing file `keybindings.json` (command `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` from the command palette), and placing the following object inside the existing array (`[ ... ]`):

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
}
```

---

**Using a *command* you can invoke from a shell *in the integrated terminal***:

Note: A truly cross-platform solution would require executing the VSCode-*internal* `workbench.action.terminal.clear` command directly from a shell, but I don't know how to do that / if it is possible at all - do tell us if you know.

- **Linux** (at least as observed on Ubuntu):

  - Use the standard `clear` utility (`/usr/bin/clear`), which also clears the scrollback buffer.
  - From PowerShell, you may also use `Clear-Host` (which calls `/usr/bin/clear`) or its built-in alias, `cls`.
  - `[Console]::Clear()` clears the scrollback buffer too, but *only* in PowerShell 7.4+ (.NET 8+).
- **macOS**:

  - As of at least macOS Sonoma (14+) `/usr/bin/clear` now *does* appear to clear the scrollback buffer too in VS Code (though, curiously, still not in regular terminals), and therefore also PowerShell's `Clear-Host`, which calls it behind the scenes.
  - On macOS Sonoma (14+) *and* PowerShell 7.4+ / .NET 8 `[Console]::Clear()` now works too.
  - Alternatively, on older versions, print the following ANSI control sequence: `'\e[2J\e[3J\e[H'` (`\e` represents the ESC char. (`0x1b`, `27`); e.g., from `bash`: `printf '\e[2J\e[3J\e[H'`; from PowerShell: `` Write-Host -NoNewLine "`e[2J`e[3J`e[H" ``
  - You can easily wrap this call in a shell script for use from any shell: create a file named, say, `cclear`, in a directory listed in your system's `PATH` variable, then make it executable with `chmod a+x`; then save the following content to it:

    ```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Clears the terminal screen *and the scrollback buffer*.
    # (Needed only on macOS, where /usr/bin/clear doesn't do the latter.)

    printf '\e[2J\e[3J\e[H'
    ```
- **Windows**:

  - As of Visual Studio Code **v1.86.1**, the standard commands - `cls` in `cmd.exe` and `Clear-Host` / `cls` in PowerShell - *do* also clear the scrollback buffer (they didn't use to), but doing so comes with ***bugs*** in the integrated terminal:

    - In `cmd.exe`, and in *PowerShell (Core)* (observed in v7.4.1) *when run inside the PIC* (the PowerShell Integrated Console, a special-purpose shell for developing PowerShell code via the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)), *one* line is unexpectedly retained in the scrollback buffer.
    - Additionally, in *PowerShell (Core)* (observed in v7.4.1), also when running as a *regular* shell, the [shell-integration decorations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/shell-integration#_command-decorations-and-the-overview-ruler) aren't reliably cleared (the marks to the left and right (scrollbar) of the terminal).
    - By contrast, *Windows PowerShell* (at least when running as a stand-alone shell) does *not* seem to have these problems.
  - As a **workaround** for the current bugs, you can override `Clear-Host` as follows (using the same ANSI/VT escape sequences that work on macOS and Linux too; place it in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file):

    ```
    function Clear-Host { 
      Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[2J$([char]27)[3J$([char]27)[H" 
    }
    ```

Comment: In ubuntu we can easily do this at the command line:  'clear; jest' to wipe the scroll buffer and run a test.     Is there a _command line_ option we can use that does the same inside of vscode for either command shell or powershell?

Comment: @alfreema, please see my update.

Comment: Bummer, we have aliases that work great in Ubuntu but haven't discovered a way to do the same in Windows because we can't clear that pesky scrollback buffer with a command.

Comment: Unfortunate, indeed, @alfreema - I suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 0):

right click on the powershell button,
then select clear,
when you are at the command window, type "clear" command, to clear the terminal window.