# fish shell: add newline before prompt only when previous output exists

Tags: bash, terminal, fish

<sup>*(Disclaimer: I am using fish, but this should apply equally to bash)*</sup>
My current shell prints a newline before the prompt so I can easily find it between command outputs.

```
# [...]
echo # newline before prompt
echo -s $arrow ' ' $cwd $git_info
echo -n -s '❯ '
```

However, the newline is also printed when there is *no previous output*, e.g. after clearing the terminal with `printf "\033c"` (or when the terminal is first opened):

```
                           <--- bad newline: no previous output
➜ /some/dir            
❯ command1            
output...             
                           <--- good newline
➜ /some/dir          
❯ command2
```

**Question:** is there any way I can get rid of this small aesthetic annoyance?

---

Edit #1:

For clarification: By "no previous output" I meant the contents of my console are empty, i.e. after (re-)initializing the terminal (because [that's all `printf "\033c"` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367075/5601145)).

Comment: Is the "(re)initializing" case the only one you are concerned with?  I was thinking you also wanted to suppress the extra newline when the previous command had no output (e.g. `export PATH` or anything like that).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes, currently that is the only case. I want every prompt prefixed by a newline _except_ after (re)initializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exec events were merged into fish-shell a few years ago. I think you can use these here. They work like event lifecycle hooks in other languages. https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/1666

As a test I made a file called postexec-newline.fish with the following:

```
function postexec_test --on-event fish_postexec
   echo
end
```

After issuing `source postexec-newline.fish`, the behavior you are describing is observed. The newline is also not visible when the screen is cleared with C-l, which I think is how such a feature should behave.

This function can live in config.fish if you want the change permanently.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution, the errant newline is now gone in newly opened sessions.

Because I am using `printf "\033c"` to clear the terminal, a newline is still inserted there. But this can probably be fixed, either by preventing this function to run, or including some condition.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: post edited to be more portable.

Here's how I do it in bash:

```sh
__PROMPT_NEWLINE=$'\nVVV '
__set_missing_newline_fix()
{
    local CURPOS
    echo -en "\033[6n" # ANSI DSR
    read -s -d R CURPOS
    CURPOS=${CURPOS#*;}
    if [ $CURPOS -eq 1 ]; then
        __MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX=""
    else
        __MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX="$__PROMPT_NEWLINE"
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=__set_missing_newline_fix
PS1="\${__MISSING_NEWLINE_FIX}\w > "
```

Note that it's configured to prefix my prompt with `VVV` to let me know that the last command did not end with a newline.

Demo:

```
$ source bashrc.sh
/tmp/so/newline > echo hello
hello
/tmp/so/newline > echo -n hello
hello
VVV /tmp/so/newline >
```

The schtick:

[ANSI DSR](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DSR-CPR.html) will cause the terminal to write its current cursor position as input. Since we're an interactive shell, that input is available to the shell's stdin, so we just `read -s` it (with no echoing).

In the above link you'll see that the response is of the form `CSI Pl; Pc R`, so we tell `read` to read up to and including the `R` with `-d R`.

Then we extract that `Pc` part using bash' "remove matching prefix" syntax `${CURPOS#*;}` which removes everything up to and including the semicolon `;`.

Then, if the cursor position is not 1, i.e. we're not at the beginning of a newline, we manually add a newline to the prompt.

ANSI DSR should work with every terminal that is ANSI compatible, but if you follow the link you'll see that it doesn't literally say `\033[6n`, but rather `CSI 6 n`. [CSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) is the beginning of an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences). Escape sequences begin with ASCII 27 ESC character (octal 033).

In my original answer I used `\E`, which bash' built-in `echo -e` command parses the same as `\033`, hence the edit above.

Comment: Is the DSR behavior dependent on the shell, terminal, or OS?

When using fish, `echo -en "\E[6n"` just gets echoed literally. In bash it always produces `;1R`, whether it's the first command or not.

Comment: Post edited, but it sounds like your terminal is not reporting correctly, does it happen in other terminals as well?

Comment: Also, how are you testing what it always produces? You need to issue the DSR when the position is not 1 (to verify...) and to read it from the terminal into something like `hexdump` so that the first ESC in the response is not swallowed by the shell or the terminal.

Comment: @Luis-Beaucamp For starters, the fish `echo` equivalent is `echo -en "\e[6n"`.  However, once we get past that, I'm still left with the blocker that fish's `read` does not seem to be able to handle this case.  It's "silent" mode does not suppress, but instead (from the man page) *"masks characters written to the terminal, replacing them with asterisks. This is useful for reading things like passwords or other sensitive information."*  It also seems as if bash's `read` automatically returns when it gets the ANSI return result, but fish's does not.  I haven't been able to get around this yet.

Comment: Oops - Missed @root's edit.  \033 is also portable to fish and correctly returns the position.  Still haven't figured out the `read` issue, though.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the uppercase `E` was the culprit. Both `e` and `033` in fish give me line and column numbers. I still have to try the reading part though, will update once done!

Comment: It appears that bash' built-in `read` does some interesting heavy lifting, I might add it to my answer since the question is tagged with `bash`, but it seems like fish automatically inserts a newline if it's missing prior to calling `fish_prompt`, so I don't think they apply equally as initially presumed.

Answer (score 1):

Stock fish already handles this (and has for years), there is no need for the prompt to do it.

When the output didn't end in a newline, you'll see a "missing newline symbol" like "¶" or "⏎", followed by a newline, and only then your prompt.

Comment: Please re-read the original question.  This is about creating a *custom* prompt where an *extra* newline is *added* (to separate the output from the next prompt) when there is output from the previous command, but is *not added* when there is no output from the previous command.  The default fish prompt never adds an *extra* (separator) newline; it only adds a single newline if, as you said, the previous output did not end in one.  This makes sure that the prompt always begins on a separate line, but does not create any visual separation that the OP is looking for.

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the confusion. I added some clarification.