# How can I clear the console screen in mac os x with shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I need some help with shell script. I'm looking for a way to clear the console screen.
I have tried to use clear but it does not work.

Comment: @anubhava `reset` does more than clear the screen and I don't think it should be used.

Comment: In normal conditions `clear` should have worked too so if that is not working for reason one needs more potent weapon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear previous output in Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-to-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

Odd.  Using `clear` works for me:

```
#/usr/bin/sh
echo 123
clear
```

Then:

```
$ chmod +x foo.sh
$ ./foo.sh
```

...clears the screen in Terminal Version 2.4 under OSX 10.9.3.

Comment: Three questions: what version of Terminal?  What version of OS X?  And what does "not work" mean?  (In Terminal, clear doesn't totally erase the screen; it scrolls the previous output up so it's not visible, but you can scroll back to it.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use AppleScript from the command shell to simulate pressing command-K in the Terminal (which corresponds to the "Clear All" menu item):

```
open -a 'Terminal.app'; osascript \
-e 'tell application "System Events"' \
-e     'tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "k" using command down' \
-e 'end tell'
```