# How to clear terminal (Mac osx) scrollback?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am looking for a simple way to clear the terminal scrollback from within a Python script. I am aware of `os.system('clear')`, however this only prints new lines, hiding the scrollback history from view, **not** deleting it. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following in Python 2:

```
>>> print '\033c',
```

and the following in Python 3:

```
>>> print('\033c', end=None)
```

These statements output <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, which is the [VT100 escape sequence for "Reset Device"](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#setup).

Comment: @James from a shell you should use `echo`, but when using `os.system()`, that messes it up slightly, so `printf` is used here instead.

Comment: `os.system("printf ...")` is highly, highly redundant: it spawns a shell process just to print something to stdout!  You can just use `print` from within Python: `print('\033\143')`

Comment: Seems more streamline. However, I did notice your method leaves a newline, as the `printf` method does not. I am not sure of the cause of this though... Possibly the newline at the end of `print`?

Comment: For Python 3, `print('\033\143', end='')`.  For Python 2, you get the ugly `print '\033\143',` (notice the trailing comma).

Comment: Actually (that link is not recommended - see [ncurses FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)), the control sequence is usually given as "Full Reset (RIS)"

Answer (score 1):

As noted, one can use a hardware reset on the terminal, i.e., `\033c`.  That works, but even for a terminal emulator can have some unwanted effects such as resetting colors.

If you were using `xterm`, that has a specific control sequence `\033[3J` which does this (see *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*, i.e., `"Ps = 3  -> Erase Saved Lines (xterm)."`).  OSX Terminal apparently does not implement that, as noted below.

For OSX-specific behavior, this question was asked before, e.g.,

- *[How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command)* which suggests using the `osascript` utility.  Interestingly enough, one of the alternatives suggested is `\033[3J`, but that does nothing on my Mac.
- *[How to clear previous output in Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-to-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x)*, with similar responses.  One (not the most popular) answer points out a problem with the simplest use of `osascript`, that it may clear the wrong window, and supplies a different answer from the following:
- [How do I reset the scrollback in the terminal via a shell command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command/31887#31887), e.g.,

  `osascript -e 'if application "Terminal" is frontmost then tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'`

(I have tested the last, and it works for me).

Comment: Hmm, looking into `\033[3J` a bit more, I found that `printf '\e[3J'` clears scrollback as well. Any best out of all 3 methods? @Dietrich @A.J.

Comment: `\e` is a bashism for `\033` (but as noted, since it did not work on my Mac, it may not work for all).