# Is there a way to keep the terminal shell prompt in the middle/top of page?

Tags: shell

I'm currently customizing my terminal/bash command prompt for my mac. I was wondering if there was a way to keep the actually prompt in the middle/top top of page after running each command. I hate when it gets to the bottom of the screen then I have to clear it to get back to the top.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2198377/5128464) might help you (there is a shortcut to clear the screen).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ANSI escape character to reposition the cursor prior displaying the prompt, but I don't think you're going to like the result; it's going to put the prompt above or on top of the output from the previous command.

```
PS1='\[\e[1;1H\]> '
```

"1;1" here represents the upper left-hand corner; you can vary the numbers to choose a different row/column if desired.

Answer (score 1):

This answer seems to nearly work for me with some amendment but it still displays some odd behaviour:

```
PS1=$'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\e[8A'"$PS1"
```

From:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698626

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. Having the prompt at the bottom hurts my neck.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the prompt at the bottom of the terminal, so I have this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
__prompt_to_bottom_line() {
  tput cup $LINES
}
alias clear='clear && __prompt_to_bottom_line'
__prompt_to_bottom_line
```

You can easily adapt it, e.g. by changing `$LINES` to `$(( LINES / 2 ))` you want it at the center of the screen.

Comment: Cool solution. I use i3/sway (tiling window manager) and when opening multiple terminals, if you don't type anything in before opening a new terminal, the previous one has its prompt move back up to the top. To resolve this I'm just using printf instead of tput:

`__prompt_to_bottom_line() { for i in $(seq $LINES); do printf "\n"; done }`

Might not be the most efficient but using `echo` instead of `printf` or dropping the for loop and abusing printf like `printf '\n%.s' $(seq $LINES)` caused me strange behaviour when opening further terminals as well.