# Is there a way to clear only the last output from terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, buffer

Is there a way to clear only the last output from terminal?

I've already read [How to clear previous output in Terminal in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-to-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x) but that clears the entire terminal (`Cmmd + K`)

I want this because say I'm done looking into something but it's taking all my screen space and I want to get rid of that, but not all the previous outputs

Comment: I you want to clear output which is _taking all my screen space_, how is that different from a way _that clears the entire terminal_?

Comment: When it's there I have to scroll up. When it's not I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally clicked on `Cmd + L` and it worked.

Looking it up here I found [terminal-mac-cheatsheet](https://github.com/0nn0/terminal-mac-cheatsheet/issues/35).