# How can I clear previous output in Terminal in Mac OS X except last n lines?

Tags: macos, shell, buffer, zsh

I know that we can clear the *entire* buffer by using one of the following, [as referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198377/how-can-i-clear-previous-output-in-terminal-in-mac-os-x):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

```sh
printf '\33c\e[3J'
```

However, is it possible to clear the entire buffer *except* the last `n` lines?

Comment: Do not think it is possible in "right way"
But you can detect window height/width and print spaces on all lines except last n lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the text on the current screen (up to the cursor position) using a different parameter (documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-J:Ps-=-1.1DDD)):

```
printf '\033[1J'
```

Unlike `\033[3J`, this is a standard sequence which you may find in ECMA-48.  Apple provides no relevant documentation.