# Delete ONLY last command and its output from VSCode integrated terminal (on Mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code

[⌘L](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac#trmlcbe3aa09:%7E:text=Clear%20to%20previous%20mark,Command%2DL) on Mac's Terminal does that, but even with disabling chords, enabling 'sendKeybindingsToShell', or even totally disabling shellIntegration, I haven't been able to use ⌘L in the VSCode's terminal.

I believe it's possible as hinted [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_custom-sequence-keybindings), but I'm not familiar with the syntax. I tried "text": "\u001b]l" to no avail.

A trick like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876027/205741) may work too.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's integrated terminal has no concept of / feature for bookmarks or marks as exist in macOS's Terminal application. A request for such a feature was raised before ([Bookmark/Marker on Terminal Panel
#68822](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68822)) and was closed as "out of scope".

I believe the closest thing that exists at the time of this writing is the builtin commands for scrolling / selecting to the next / previous command. Ex. `Terminal: Scroll to Next Command` (runnable from the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> on Windows/Linux. Either that, or finding some way to make use of ANSI escape codes like the clearing/erasing ones in [the CSI family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences), but I'm not sure how you'd achieve that (you'd need to be able to get the number of lines the output and command take up).

If you want to get such a feature to clear the display buffer to the previous command/"mark", then you'll need to [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: First link is a good find. Matter of fact it does demonstrate that it can scroll to prev/next command and I just tried it with ⌘Up/Down and it worked. They just don't have builtin support for ⌘L yet. If I could find the part of code that handles ⌘Up/Down, I could most likely be able to add support for ⌘L too.

Comment: @Unknown https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4f7a76b792d38dcf576c831efc3f5c40cd6624e2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalActions.ts#L851. Please link me to whatever contribution you make. feature-request or pull-request.

Comment: I'd tell you but then I'd have to... :)